# TS Abstract method implementation can define any element of union-type as parameter

Tags: typescript

The following code throws no type error (as of TypeScript 4.1.2):

```js
abstract class Abstract {
    abstract method(x: string | number): void;
}

class Implementation extends Abstract {
    method(x: string): void {
        // do exciting string stuff
    }
}
```

I interpret this code as:

> All implementations of `Abstract` must have a `method` that takes a single (`string` or `number`) parameter.

Therefore I would expect the TypeScript compiler to complain about `Implementation` not properly implementing the abstract `method`, since the parameter type does not match (`number` is not allowed as a parameter of `method`).

However, it seems as if the compiler interprets this code as:

> All implementations of `Abstract` must have a `method` that takes a single (`string` parameter) or (`number` parameter).

This interpretation means that the following code is completely valid (according to the compiler):

```js
const x: Abstract = new Implementation();
x.method(4);
```

This will of course lead to issues, because `Implementation.method` only expects a `string` as parameter.

Am I missing something about how union parameters are treated, or have I stumbled on a compiler bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an *intentional* bit of [unsoundness](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness) in TypeScript.  Method parameters are checked [*bivariantly*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance), meaning that if a superclass (or supertype) has a method that accepts a parameter of type `A`, and a subclass (or subtype) has the same method that accepts a parameter of type `B`, the compiler will accept it if *either* `A` is assignable to `B` (checked *contravariantly*, which is safe), *or* if `B` is assignable to `A` (checked *covariantly*, which is *unsafe*).  It's not restricted to union types; `string` is assignable to `string | number`, so the compiler accepts it.

So *why* is this allowed?  There is [a FAQ entry about it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant).  If method parameters were strictly enforced to be covariant, the compiler would, among other things, not allow you to treat arrays covariantly.  Right now, the compiler accepts that `Array<string>` is assignable to `Array<string | number>`.  This is very convenient, but technically unsafe.  Everything is fine if you're just reading elements, but it lets you inadvertently `push()` a `number` into an `Array<string>`:

```
const arrString: Array<string> = ["a", "b", "c"];
const arrStringOrNumber: Array<string | number> = arrString; // no error
arrStringOrNumber.push(1); // uh oh

arrString.map(x => x.toUpperCase()); // ERROR AT RUNTIME! x.toUpperCase not a function
```

This kind of unsoundness is, for better or worse, baked into the language.  Even without methods, the compiler generally treats *object properties* as covariant, again, very convenient, but unsafe, because *writing* to properties covariantly has the same problem:

```
function acceptStringOrNumberProp(x: { prop: string | number }) {
    x.prop = 1;
}

const strProp = { prop: "hello" };
acceptStringOrNumberProp(strProp); // no error! 
strProp.prop.toUpperCase(); // ERROR AT RUNTIME! strProp.prop.toUpperCase not a function
```

Convenience wins out over type safety.

---

Note that it used to be the case that *all* function parameters were checked bivariantly.  This was changed when TypeScript 2.6 introduced [the `--strictFunctionTypes` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html) and added it to the `--strict` suite of flags.  Now at least non-method functions will prevent this kind of thing:

```
type Func = (x: string | number) => void;
const impl: Func = (x: string) => console.log(x.toUpperCase()); // error after TS2.6 strict
//    ~~~~ <--
//     Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I guess the added strictness didn't lead to too much inconvenience for non-method functions.  But for the foreseeable future, you need to deal with this for methods.

---

One possible workaround is to represent the "method" as a function-valued property.  This doesn't really work with `class` declarations (because the compiler will be unhappy if you override something that looks like an instance property with a prototype method), but you can do this:

```
interface Abstract2 {
    method: (x: string | number) => void;
}

class Implementation2 implements Abstract2 {
    method(x: string): void { // error!
    //~~~~ <--       Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        // do exciting string stuff
    }
}
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.1.2#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgguadEG8BYAKATIVEhngQFsBTCACwHsATACgA8AuBKgJYA7AOYIAPgiEBXWiHpQAlHwBuLAWwDcJAL4kSKNBgCStAA7J6DIRGAQBLIQnpcI9IWwzYqeBEVLkDMzs3HyCosoIahp+JOTxCAD0iQhsLM5csAL2ovzQwmKQ0gBmxXHkesSVBo6QFFBQAMr5onyYDcAAngA84SIAfAgAvAgA2gBEwOMANAjjIDNzsOMAutrEsLWIwA3NUAUA8lAAcrLyUG0dPX0SUmcKgyM7TS0imkkpQukKUCxQAIQkZ57Q4ne5QAB0ZmkYCYHAAjIp3skENImAgWEx9MRga8IbRgGZuMNBlwIRAWABVMxmBQAYTQ9A4iiRHwQAFEAEqcg6crAAFQQnMpx35xgAsuz-ggyRTqbSoAywPQpCxtghitIhPAHEJsSRNdr7I4KLBYPQzBAQaIjqc5AoAAq-Im8PwIMzOsKvW4ye1QBA6RSxAJkMkelhmYYIeHraobLZ5KBOiNR-Duz1zJj0ZDIFjjAPrODmy3WkS28HJolUSuslFfZwNP7SkjV51Qttymn0xnM5EpLk8vmYQXC0USqWJyvtiPkqldxWM1Xqw06xzYiCdWkIABiWtgUdCiYKPvBQaGg2iWhqQjqAnMyD4u+1B9dfTPg02N5YlghuZE3FneVu2VZlaxSH4-goYo3H9flGgAJghAA2I94BIFFyAAP2wzCEG6ABafD0JSeJ+U3FUAHIbkkX1zgohABAwL5tnQAQRCEUBLAQCluPIhAqNeCiIX1YhhBg4o4BVbxcHgeDg3iIJWDYPhD2ou4-XfKJ1CvKpsUMdAEFMCwrHcWxjSEOS72M6wIC8HBqAgOT-AUxglNU15IkvN0UQggFyjIZIcNwgj8ISMgyK3AT9lyGjwXoxilwoVj2M4lUeI3SK+iE-yEhRNIMiyHJCm9IpShyypKiAA)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Is there a reason why the `strictFunctionTypes` exception was not extended to this situation? I can't think of a case where it would be convenient but still (mostly) 'valid' to implement abstract methods like this.

Comment: Shouldn't this sentence be flipped: "the compiler accepts that `Array<string | number>` is assignable to `Array<string>`"? I can assign `Array<string>` to `Array<string | number>`, not the other way around.

Comment: I don't know if anyone considered abstract methods as a special case; it's definitely true that methods in general are sometimes used in an unsafe way on purpose.  I can take the "event listener" example from the handbook and change it into an abstract class like [this](https://tsplay.dev/DmMkkw).  Of course, there are *better* ways to do that which don't rely on unsoundness... but the same could be said of the example from the handbook.  Personally I would love to see this changed... if you want covariant arrays you should use `ReadonlyArray`.  But apparently this is how it is.

Comment: Flipping the `Array<string | number>`/`Array<string>` sentence: oops, fixed